Is PDF signature appearance taken into account in the bytes that are signed in a iText PDF document signature?
I am signing a PDF document with iText and I want to do it in two steps: first make a request to my java spring application to obtain the bytes to be signed, and then make another request to sign them.
What I would like to know is whether the signature appearance is taken into account in those bytes or not, that is to say, if the signature appearance is added to the signature or if it is only an esthetical aspect. If it is not taken into account I will not prepare the signature appearance when requesting for the bytes to be signed so I don't do it twice.

The original appearance of the signature is part of the signed data. The only part of the file that is not signed is the placeholder hex string in which the CMS signature container is eventually embedded.
(At least that's the case for interoperable signatures. Strictly speaking the spec allows for arbitrary signed data ranges, everything except the placeholder is merely recommended there. But if you want your signatures to be accepted by PDF signature validators, you'll find that most of them require the whole PDF revision except the placeholder to be signed.)
Depending on the MDP security settings of the signed PDF, you can append certain changes to the file; in particular, changing the appearance may be allowed! But validators usually will point out the change, either specifically or generically.

ok, so if I calculate the bytes to be signed without configuring a signature appearance for the document, and then I sign the document configuring an appearance for it but using the previously calculated bytes the signature will be invalid right?

Yes. Re-calculating the digest will be fickle anyways: The PDF contains information like creation and modification times, and they also are in the signed content. Also, if you happen to encrypt the PDF, there are PDF encryption modes that employ random numbers. You'd need to make sure that the same random numbers are used.

Trying to answer the implied question - How to sign a pdf in multiple phases? i.e -

Get the hash of the singable part of pdf
Externally sign the hash
Attach the signature on the pdf

In the context of itext-core java library(v8 as of date of writing this answer), the following attributes would have to be kept same for Steps #1 & #3 above to achieve a valid signature -

All the Signature related parameters, like - Signer, Reason, Location, Page No, Position on Page, Sign Date-Time, Signature Appearance, Signature Field Name, Signature Field Appearance Name, Digest Algo, Sign Algo; These are so far directly controllable via iText library methods. Additionally ..
DocumentID generated by com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfEncryption.generateNewDocumentId()
PDF Modification Date as controlled by PdfName.ModDate key in PdfDocument Object -> PdfDocumentInfo attribute "info" -> PdfDictionary attribute "infoDictionary"

The "DocumentID" and "PDF Modification Date" are not directly accessible via library calls, and would either require recompiling the library from source or hot-patching the calls using some runtime code generation and manipulation library.
If one manages to keep the attributes mentioned above constant during the get-hash and sign calls. Then the hash extraction is quite simple. To extract the hash for signing, one can create a custom com.itextpdf.signatures.IExternalSignature object by using an anonymous inner class and implement the methods as follows -
byte[] extracted;
IExternalSignature hashExtractor = 
return new IExternalSignature() {
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(byte[] hash) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        extracted = hash;
        return new byte[0];
    }

    @Override
    public String getDigestAlgorithmName() {
        return "SHA-256";
    }

    @Override
    public String getSignatureAlgorithmName() {
        return "RSA";
    }

    @Override
    public ISignatureMechanismParams getSignatureMechanismParameters() { return null; }

};

Using the created custom IExternalSignature object as an argument to the pdfSignerObj.signDetached(...) call, the to-be-signed hash will be extracted. This concludes the step #1.
For step #2, the extracted hash bytes would need to be signed from appropriate signing source - p12 file, hardware token, HSM. The implementations may vary.
For step #3 - Keeping all other things done in step #1 as it is but replacing the hashExtractor with a signInjector IExternalSignature object. Which instead of exporting the hash bytes, would return the signature bytes, as defined in a local variable. Eg -
byte[] signature = <signature bytes>;
IExternalSignature signInjector = 
return new IExternalSignature() {
    @Override
    public byte[] sign(byte[] hash) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        return signature;
    }
    ...
};

The resulting file should have a valid signature.
